# How do I globally change the style of the horizontal rule when using RMarkdown to pdf?

Tags: pandoc, rmarkdown

I am using `R Markdown` and `Latex` with `memoir` to compile a book to pdf. The author has used the `***` syntax for horizontal dividers. Checking the compiled `.tex` file I can see that the conversion from markdown is to:

```
\begin{center}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5pt}\end{center}
```

How do I globally style `\rule`?

Just in case it helps, I found this snippet online that changes the color but have not idea how to modify it to affect the width and thickness:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{blue}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: How should the rule look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to use a lua filter for pandoc to modify the rules generated by `***`.

First you have to look up, how the horizontal rule is represented in pandoc's AST. You can do that by using `native` as the output format:

```
echo "* * *" | pandoc --from markdown --lua-filter=hl.lua --to native
```

Which returns: `[HorizontalRule]`, now you know the element is called `HorizontalRule`. To change the output, you need a small program that looks for the element in question and returns the code you want:

```
-- horizontalrule.lua

if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
  function HorizontalRule ()
    return {
      pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\rule'),
    }
  end
end
```

[image]

Change `'\\rule'` to whatever you want and call pandoc with the option `--lua-filter=horizontalrule.lua`